# Backbone collection is not a constructor

Tags: backbone.js, collections, requirejs

I've already checked the answers from people that have apparently the same problem but I haven't been able to fix my problem yet.

I have a view (`teacher.profile.js`) which is calling a collection (`levels.js`) which has a collection (`subject.js`), but when I load the page the subject collection is always `undefined` and said not to be a constructor.

After refreshing so many times, sometimes the second one, the `subject` collection is there and works.

Could anyone tell me what is wrong, please?

Thanks

**subject.js**

```
    define(["GB"], function(GB) {

      var subjectModel = GB.Model.extend({
        idAttribute:"subjectId",
        defaults: {
          subjectId: '',
          name: '',
          levelId: '',
          selected: false
        }
      });

      return subjectModel;
    });
```

**subjects.js**

```
define([
      "GB",
      "modules/register/teacher/models/subject"],
      function (GB, SubjectModel) {

      var subjectCollection = GB.Collection.extend({
        model: SubjectModel,
        url: "webapi/api/Administration/Subject"
      });

      return subjectCollection;
    });
```

**level.js**

```
    define(['GB', 'modules/register/teacher/models/subjects'], function (GB, SubjectCollection) {

      var levelModel = GB.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
          levelId: '',
          name: '',
          iconClass: '',
          subjects: ''
        },
        parse: function(attrs) {
          **attrs.subjects = new SubjectCollection(attrs.subjects);** //Here is where the error is thrown. SubjectCollection is not a constructor.
          return attrs;
        }
      });

      return levelModel;
    });
```

**levels.js**

```
    define(["GB", "modules/register/teacher/models/level"], function (GB, LevelModel) {

      var levelCollection = GB.Collection.extend({
        model: LevelModel,
        url: "webapi/api/Administration/Level"
      });

      return levelCollection;
    });
```

**teacher.profile.js** view

```
define([
      "GB",
      "tpl!modules/register/teacher/teacherProfile",  "modules/register/teacher/subject.level"
    ], function(GB, Template, SubjectLevelView) {
      var view = GB.Views.Item.extend({
        template: Template,
        ui: {
          subjects: "#subject-list",
          levels: "#level-list",
          infoTitle: "#info-title",
          subjectsLevels: "#subjects-levels"
        },
        initialize: function() {
          this.userLevels = [];
        },
        onRender: function() {
          var self = this;
          this.ui.infoTitle.text(GB.Localise("teacher-data-title"));
          var levelsPromise = this.collection.fetch();
          $.when(levelsPromise)
            .then(function() {
              var levelsSubjects = _.map(self.collection.models, function(item) {
                if (item.get("subjects").length > 0) {
                  var view = new SubjectLevelView({ model: item });
                  self.userLevels.push(item);
                  return view.render().el;
                }
              });
              self.ui.subjectsLevels.append(levelsSubjects);
            });
        }
      });
      return view;
    });
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
      map: {
          '*': {
              'css': 'plugins/require-css/css',
              'tpl': 'plugins/require.lodash.template', //this is our templating helper tpl!.html, its brings the template in already underscored, this is faster slightly than text! & subsequent template
              'lodash': 'underscore'
          }
      },
      paths: {
          'plugins': '../plugins',
          'styles':'../css',
          'localisation':'core/localisation',
          'jquery': '../lib/jquery-2.1.4',
          'jquery.browser': '../plugins/jquery.browser',
          'jquery.video': '../plugins/vide/jquery.vide',
          'waypoints': '../plugins/waypoints/jquery.waypoints',
          'backbone': '../lib/backbone',
          'marionette': '../lib/backbone.marionette',
          'text': '../lib/text',
          'underscore': '../lib/lodash.underscore', //yes underscore is now lodash - its a better performer + extra features + no downside :)
          'lodash': '../lib/lodash.underscore',
          'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap',
          'bootstrap-dialog': '../plugins/bootstrap-dialog/js/bootstrap-dialog',
          'modernizr': '../lib/modernizr-2.8.3',
          'backbone.validation': '../plugins/backbone-validation',
          'themepunch.tools': '../plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min',
          'themepunch.rev': '../plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min',
          'smoothscroll': '../plugins/SmoothScroll',
          'json': '../plugins/requirejs-plugins/json',
          'cldr': '../plugins/localisation/cldrjs/cldr',
          'cldr-data': '../plugins/localisation/cldr-data',
          'globalize': '../plugins/localisation/globalize/globalize',
          'localise':'localisation/localise',
          'GB': 'app'
      },
      shim: {
          'marionette': {
              deps: ['backbone'],
              exports: 'Marionette'
          },
          'backbone': {
              deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
              exports: 'Backbone'
          },
          'underscore': {
              exports: '_'
          },
          'backbone.validation': {
              deps: ['backbone', 'underscore']
          },
          'bootstrap': {
              deps: ['jquery'],
          },
          'bootstrap-dialog': {
              deps: ['bootstrap'],
          },
          'smoothscroll': {
              deps: ['jquery.browser']
          },
          'themepunch.tools': {
              deps: ['jquery']
          },
          'themepunch.rev': {
              deps: ['themepunch.tools']
          },
          'jquery.browser': {
              deps: ['jquery']
          },
          'waypoints': {
              deps: ['jquery']
          },
          'jquery.video': {
              deps: ['jquery']
          },
          'globalize': {
              deps: ['cldr']
          },
          'json': {
              deps: ['text']
          }
      }
  });
  require([
      "GB",
      "routes/application.router",
      "bootstrap",
      "core/validation"],
      function (GB, AppRouter) {
          GB.routers.application = new AppRouter();
          GB.start();
      });
```

**app.js**

```
    define([
        "marionette",
        "core/GB.ini",
        "globalize",
        "localisation/localise",
        "bootstrap-dialog",
        "json!cldr-data/supplemental/likelySubtags.json",
        "json!cldr-data/supplemental/plurals.json",
        "json!cldr-data/supplemental/timeData.json",
        "json!cldr-data/supplemental/weekData.json",
        "json!localisation/messages/es.json",
        "globalize/number",
        "globalize/message",
        "globalize/plural",
        "modernizr",
        "smoothscroll",
    ],
        function (Marionette, AppIni, Globalize, Localise, Dialog, LikeSubtags, Plurals, TimeData, WeekData, Messages) {
            var GB = window.GB = new Marionette.Application();
            GB.User = {};
            GB.routers = {};

            Globalize.load(
                LikeSubtags,
                Plurals,
                TimeData,
                WeekData
            );
            Globalize.loadMessages(Messages);
            Globalize.locale("es");

            GB.Globalize = Globalize;
            GB.Localise = Localise;
            GB.Dialog = Dialog;

            GB.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
            GB.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

            GB.Views = {
                //if we do expand on these views they should probably get their own file.
                Item: Marionette.ItemView.extend({}), //for a single model
                Collection: Marionette.CollectionView.extend({}), //for a collection
                Composite: Marionette.CompositeView.extend({}), //for a combination of a model and a collection
                Layout: Marionette.LayoutView.extend({})
            };

            GB.session = new GB.Model();

            GB.getUrl = function () {
                return Backbone.history.location.origin + Backbone.history.location.pathname;
            }

            GB.getCurrentRoute = function () {
                return Backbone.history.fragment;
            };



            GB.on("before:start", function () {
                var RegionContainer = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
                    el: "#app-container",

                    regions: {
                        header: "#header-wrapper",
                        main: "#main-region",
                        footer: "#footer-region",
                        dialog: "#dialog-region"
                    }
                });

                GB.regions = new RegionContainer();

            });

            GB.on("start", function () {
              require(["modules/header/header.module"], function () {
                    GB.Header.Controllers.Overview.show();
                });
              require(["modules/footer/footer.module"], function () {
                    GB.Footer.Controllers.Overview.show();
                });
                AppIni.start();
                Backbone.history.start();
                if (GB.getCurrentRoute() === "")
                    Backbone.history.navigate("#home", { trigger: true });
            });

            return GB;
        });
```

Foder Structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwTta.png)

Comment: can you show an example of the fetched `json`?

Comment: Here you go, its in the teacher.profile view.                            GB.session.Levels = new LevelCollection();
var levelsPromise = GB.session.Levels.fetch();

Comment: That's not the fetched `json`.

Comment: _"said not to be a constructor"_, could you point the exact line where the error occurs?

Comment: Also, when asked for clarifications, please include the details into your question by editing it.

Comment: It's done, I've included more details into the question. Is it useful?

Comment: Can you inspect and confirm `SubjectCollection` is a function? It could be that the path is wrong, or you're returning something other than the constructor function itself from the require module (but it looks ok in shared code though)

Comment: @MarcelaMoreno Your code for `level.js` shows it loading `"modules/register/models/subjects"` with a plural at the end. However, earlier you show the code to `subject.js`, which is singular. Is this just a typo? Are you showing the wrong code?

Comment: Yes sorry. I'm trying to code in a different way to see if there is something worng in the other way but I'm still having the problem.

Comment: What's in your `app.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my first guess was that `parse` method on the levelModel is never being called. But it should always be called on `fetched`. Moreover, I reread your question and saw that sometimes it did work for you.

So my second guess now is a `race condition` with `requirejs`. i.e: sometimes inside `levels.js` SubjectCollection is a real `Backbone Collection` and sometimes is undefined.

One of the reason for such a `race` can be [`Circular Dependencies`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#circular). Can you share the full source? or verify that you dont have such a `circulation`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don;t need to call the parse method, it's called when I fetched the collection. In the view teacher.profile js file is where I'm calling the fetch of Levels collection. See the render of my view. I've already checked the circular reference cos I've read from another post but  view is calling the levels collection and level collection create the subject collection.

Comment: Any idea what is happening? I'm still have the error and check everything you told me. Do you need me to share more code? Thx

Comment: Hey there,  if you can share the code online/offline so it can be debugged it can sure help.